# Group multiple rows into one without using COALESCE

Tags: sql

If I have a table as below:

```
Date    Name    Number    Period1    Period2    Period3  
-------------------------------------------------------
23-Oct  Barry   453       NULL       NULL       Room 4
23-Oct  Barry   453       NULL       Room 8     NULL
24-Oct  Barry   453       Room 2     NULL       NULL
23-Oct  Mary    139       Room 3     NULL       Room 4
23-Oct  Mary    139       NULL       Room 6     NULL
24-Oct  Mary    139       NULL       NULL       Room 9
24-Oct  Mary    139       Room 1     NULL       NULL
```

How can I best query it so as to get the output below, i.e. grouped by date, person and and periods?

```
Date    Name    Number    Period1    Period2    Period3  
-------------------------------------------------------
23-Oct  Barry   453       NULL       Room 8     Room 4
23-Oct  Mary    139       Room 3     Room 6     NULL
24-Oct  Barry   453       Room 2     NULL       NULL
24-Oct  Mary    139       Room 1     NULL       Room 9
```

Comment: I assume the third column is supposed to be titled "Period3"?

Comment: The question is vague.  If there is more than one value for any period column, which one do you want?

Comment: Yes, it was meant to be period 3. And there will only ever be 1 value per person per date per column, although I've since realised that you can use MAX() and MIN() on varchars... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Date,
       Name,
       Number,
       MAX(Period1) AS Period1,
       MAX(Period2) AS Period2,
       MAX(Period3) AS Period3
FROM   T
GROUP  BY Date,
          Name,
          Number
```

Comment: Assuming he wants max values of course.  I find the question unclear.

Comment: @DanBracuk - The sample data only has one value per group so `MAX` or `MIN` is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks - I'm an idiot. Had it in my head that MAX() and MIN() couldn't be used on varchar fields!